# UITableViewCell's implementation of -layoutSubviews needs to call super

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, masonry-ios-osx

I add a view in UITableViewCell , and use mas_makeConstraints (Masonry)

```
UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:kMASCellReuseIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];

UIView * view =[[UIView alloc]init];

view.backgroundColor=[UIColor redColor];

[cell addSubview:view];

[view mas_makeConstraints:^(MASConstraintMaker *make){
    make.right.equalTo(cell).offset(-20);
    make.centerY.equalTo(cell);
    make.width.height.equalTo(@20);
}];
```

but it not work.

error message:
Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'Auto Layout still required after executing -layoutSubviews. UITableViewCell's implementation of -layoutSubviews needs to call super.'

please help me ! @.@

Comment: You should be adding view to the cell's contentView (and the constraints should be made to it too) not the cell. It would also be better to put this code in the cell's init method rather than cellForRowAtIndexPath. The way your code is written now, you will be adding view every time the cell is reused.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Better yet, why not just make a custom `UITableViewCell` and add the views you need to it, via IB.

Comment: thanks for your idea!
but i dont't like IB。
how just use code to make a custom UITableViewCell ?
i try . it work fine in ios7.
but ios6 don't work.
error message: UITableViewCell's implementation of -layoutSubviews needs to call super

Comment: Add it to the cells contentView rather. That should do the trick.